# Какие есть ограничения на сериализацию/десериализацию делегатов?

Tags: serialize, .net-4.0, .net-4.5, .net

Интересует версия `.Net 4.5` или `.Net 4.0`.
В сети есть информация, интересуют последние версии '.Net', может там что-то изменилось?

**UPD**

```
[Serializable] 
class A
{
    public Action action;

    public A()
    {
        this.action = new Action(this.action1);
    }        

    void action1()
    { }
}

[Serializable]
class B
{
    A a = new A();

    public B()
    {
        a.action = new Action(this.action2);
    }

    void action2()
    { }
}
```

- Пусть, например, `wcf-служба` имеет
  метод с параметром `Stream`, который
  содержит сериализованный объект `B`.
- Или, например, [делаем копию
  объекта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloni
  ng-objects-in-c-sharp) методом сериализации/десериализации.

[Статья](http://jakub-linhart.blogspot.com/2011/05/delegates-serialization-limits.html) про ограничения сериализации делегатов.

*Что произойдет при сериализации/десериализации объектов `A` и `B`?*

Comment: А что могло поменяться? Expression Tree единственное адекватное, что можно получить и попытаться сериализовать/десериализовать.

Вот только какова область применения...

Сколько не пытался логику "вынести" в отдельный файлик, ничего путного из этого не выходило.

Comment: @Spawn, вопрос обновил.

Comment: Ничего не произойдёт, свойств-то нет. А если и будет свойство, то делегат не имеет беспараметрического конструктора, так что его сериализовать стандартными средствами не получится. Выход - IXmlSerializable, например, но что Вы будете делать с Action? :)

Как я уже написал, разве что Expression Tree делать...

Comment: Привет. Недавно тоже работал с WCF, и тоже задавал вопрос про сериализацию и десериализацию:
[Вот тут][1] , думаю поможет :)


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/206262/net-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-c

Comment: @IVsevolod, у меня вопрос конкретно про сериализацию свойств-делегатов.

Comment: @ildar, да я это уже понял ) вопрос с начало неправильно прочитал )

Comment: @Spawn, у меня есть рабочий пример класса `B`, который нормально сериализуется/десериализуется. Пока только не оттестировано, поэтому, что бы потом не переделывать, спрашиваю, корректно ли поддерживается сериализация делегатов?

Comment: Хорошо, бинарный формат, всё что угодно положили, считали, воссоздали, а зачем оно вообще надо?

Обычно такие костыли начинаются когда не получается сделать иначе.

Помимо этого, Вы на стороне клиента Reference на библиотеку будете делать? Смысл тогда делегаты передавать?

Comment: Обмен Stream'ом удобно и в зависимости от постановки задачи даже нужно, но зачем там делегат, учитывая, что Reference делается?

Comment: Почему костыли? Обмениваться данными с wcf stream'ом просто и удобно или я ошибаюсь? Reference на библиотеку делаю. Смысл вопроса не "для чего нужны делегаты", а "ограничения сериализации делегатов".  
**UPD**  

    [Serializable] 
    class A
    {
        public Action action;
    
        public A()
        {
            setMode(1)
        }
    
 public setMode(int mode)
 {
  switch (mode)
  {
   case 1:
    this.action = new Action(this.action1);
    break;
   case 2:
    this.action = new Action(this.action2);
    break;
  }
 }
  
        void action1()
 { }
 void action2()
 { }
    }